# How to have user comments show only when they are loged in

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a website for my car club where the members can log in and submit there own runs on one page, I would like to show the comments for the member that is logged in only so they can't see anyone else run, but at the same time, an admin can see all comments. The comment form has been modified with special boxes for the car type, rego, date and time. I used the comments fields plugin to add these boxes.
[image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyaRr.png)

I have tried many codes from the internet but they do not show all the details that have been entered

```
comment_form(); 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
       $args = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
        'order' =>  'DESC',
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
        echo '<p>'; 
        echo( $comment->comment_author. '<br/>'
.$comment->comment_date.

 '<br/>' .$comment->comment_content. '<br/><hr>' 
);

        echo '</p>';
    endforeach;
}
```

Only shows the comment box results not the extra boxes car type, rego, date and time, besides that it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the right code

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
       $args = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
        'order' =>  'DESC',

        'user_id' => $user_id

    );
    $comments = get_comments($args); 
     foreach($comments as $comment) :
         echo '<p>'; 
        echo ('<b>'
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'name', true )
.$comment->comment_author
.'</b> submitted on the <b>' 
.$comment->comment_date
.' </b>A Impromptu Run</b>
 <li><b>Car:- </b>' 
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'car', true )
. '</li><li><b>Rego No:-</b> '  
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rego', true )
. '</li><li><b>Date No:-</b>' 
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'date', true )
. '</li><li><b>Start Time:-</b>' 
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'time', true )
.'<br><b> Details </b><br>'
 .$comment->comment_content
.' <br><i> '
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'name', true )
.' I acknowledge that the driver has a current drivers licence, that the '
.get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'car', true )
.' is registered, and listed in the ???? car list.</i>'
. '<br/><hr>' 
);
        echo '</p>';
    endforeach;
}
```